# Twitter Bootstrap - Scrolling to #ID using Carousel Images

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on twitter bootstrap carousel in a project and have to customize it to apply a custom animation like marquee tag animation. Each item should slide like marquee text element.

I am stuck here and cannot go ahead. Do i have to specify some scrolling time to delay the scrolling between items or something else? (I know we can use *interval* attribute for time to delay between automatically cycling an item, but i could not achieve marquee effect using it)

Comment: Do you mean you want it to constantly scroll? If so then there is no built in functionality for that - you'd have to try and customise it yourself. Probably best to look at another pre-built carousel that does what you want.

Comment: @BillyMoat thanks for the reply billy. I mean not exactly constantly scroll, when user click on prev/next button the carousel item should side with html marquee scroll animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you...

---

### Step 1

Add this JavaScript to your page.

```
$(function() {
    function filterPath(string) {
        return string
                .replace(/^\//, '')
                .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '')
                .replace(/\/$/, '');
    }
    var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
    var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

    $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
        var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
        if (locationPath == thisPath
                && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
                && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
            var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
            if (target) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $(this).click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
                        location.hash = target;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });

    // use the first element that is "scrollable"
    function scrollableElement(els) {
        for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i < argLength; i++) {
            var el = arguments[i],
                    $scrollElement = $(el);
            if ($scrollElement.scrollTop() > 0) {
                return el;
            } else {
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop() > 0;
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                if (isScrollable) {
                    return el;
                }
            }
        }
        return [];
    }
});
```

### Step 2

Add an `<a href="#ID"></a>` around the images in the carousel - with the ID of the containing element you want to scroll to inserted in the `href="#ID"`

Then make sure there is a div on the page with the matching ID (if there is not, it won't do anything).

This works amazingly well for me - I know bootstrap will probably have something like this built in, but this works 100% of the time.

Cheers!

*I can't remember where I got this code, but if anyone knows I'd like to give credit to them as it's an awesome piece of code.*